# Exception when there's an overload of an event handler

Tags: windows-phone-8

In windows phone 8, if there's a xaml file that references an OnFooClick event handler in the code behind, if it happens to exist another OnFooClick method with a different signature on the same class, the app blows up at startup with this exception:

`MS.Internal.WrappedException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. ---> System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure_WithDesiredSize(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure_WithDesiredSize(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(UIElement child, Size layoutSlotSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---`

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I've encountered exactly the same problem, at least I have exactly the same exception message. I've run out of ideas, please someone help here...

Comment: Just rename one of the methods

Comment: Thank you for posting this, Gustavo!

Answer (score 0):

this exception is because of poor binding. have u use any toolkit in your xaml. if you try to bind any value under the toolkit sometimes this kind of exceptions will arise.

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes if we forget to name control by just giving declaration like
x:name=""